# Accidentally removed all Wine files

Tags: wine, rm

I was finding that if any way to remove the installed windows program in ubuntu. then i found a forum here http://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#uninstall_app. 
then i type in terminal

```
cd $HOME
rm -rf .wine

rm -f $HOME/.config/menus/applications-merged/wine*
rm -rf $HOME/.local/share/applications/wine
rm -f $HOME/.local/share/desktop-directories/wine*
rm -f $HOME/.local/share/icons/????_*.{xpm,png}
rm -f $HOME/.local/share/icons/*-x-wine-*.{xpm,png}
```

then I saw all my files in C (desktop,Downloads, documents around 30 GB) is missing.

Please help to get my missing files.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to be the bearer of bad news, you will have to restore your windows files from the last backup.

(With the rm -rf .wine command you have not only wiped the entire wine settings but all programs and DATA in there. rm -rf XYZ is the 'nuke everything inside XZY' command in unix systems, use only if you know what you are doing)

You can remove installed programs in wine using the 'deinstall wine applications' applet, no need to get brute force normally. If you can't remove some wine application, go into the .wine folder and selectively delete only the directory of the application.

If you don't have backup, (but please say you do) and the files are important, then you will have to do an emergency data recovery on that disk. First action is then to STOP USING THE DISK IMMEDIATELY and get professional advice because every second you use the system, more of your deleted file contents will get overwritten.

Comment: Any progress on this?